# Titlesec ignores odd and even page formatting for chapters

Tags: titlesec

I am trying to format the appearance of the chapters depending if they appear on an even or odd page. Based on the documentation of titlesec it should work with the option `page=even` and `page=odd`. This works for sections but not for chapters. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=22mm, left=45mm, right=25mm, bottom=30mm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[rigidchapters,explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{name=\section,page=odd}{}{ODD:}{.5em}{}
\titleformat{name=\section,page=even}{}{EVEN:}{.5em}{}
\begin{document}
\chapter{ChapterA}
\section{Section a} \lipsum[1-2]
\section{Section b} \lipsum[1-2]
\section{Section c} \lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{ChapterB}
\section{Section a} \lipsum[1-2]
\section{Section b} \lipsum[1-2]
\section{Section c} \lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{ChapterC}
\section{Section a} \lipsum[1-2]
\section{Section b} \lipsum[1-2]
\section{Section c} \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

If you replace both `\chapter` in the titlesec command with `\section` it works.

Is there a reason for that? How can i use a different `\titleformat` command for odd and even pages?

Comment: Minority view: Whatever you want to do with `titlesec`, you can either do more easily without or more easily do without. Majority view: it is the only game in town. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `titlesec` doesn't act much on the standard way for typesetting chapter titles, that is, it still relies on `\@makechapterhead`.

You have to redeclare the title class:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=22mm, left=45mm, right=25mm, bottom=30mm}

\usepackage[rigidchapters]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleclass{\chapter}{top}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,page=odd}{}{ODD:}{.5em}{}
\titleformat{name=\chapter,page=even}{}{EVEN:}{.5em}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{ChapterA}
\section{Section a} \lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{ChapterB}
\section{Section a} \lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved the problem! I still have to research why the line `\titleclass{\chapter}{top}` made the difference, but it was very simple to use.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it seems that the `page` option doesn't take effect for `\chapter`.

You can work around this by declaring something like:

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter}{\Huge}{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}{ODD:}{EVEN:}}{.5em}{}
```

with the help of `\ifthenelse` from the `ifthen` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=22mm, left=45mm, right=25mm, bottom=30mm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[rigidchapters,explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\titleformat{name=\section,page=odd}{}{ODD:}{.5em}{}
\titleformat{name=\section,page=even}{}{EVEN:}{.5em}{}
\titleformat{name=\chapter}{\Huge}{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}{ODD:}{EVEN:}}{.5em}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{ChapterA}
\section{Section A} \lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{ChapterB}
\section{Section B} \lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{ChapterC}
\section{Section C} \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Output (needs two compilations, at least!)

[image]